# Can I access the DB queries counter programmatically in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I find the Symfony2 toolbar very useful, especially the DB queries counter all the way to the right.
The program I'm writing needs to access this value before returning a response, in my case, redirecting to another url.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how you can access it in functional tests.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/profiling.html

Comment: Thank you, it's a great answer. It looks like it's impossible to access the information from a controller or custom service at runtime though.